# How can I insert a PHP code snippet in markdown of Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, markdown

I want to write a PHP code snippet in the question or answer. I searched that but Stack Overflow can insert only HTML, CSS, JavaScript snippet code.

How can I insert a PHP code snippet like below?

JavaScript snippet example:

```js
console.log('hello world');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow has no features for executing live demos of PHP code in questions.

You should format a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a regular code block:

````
```php
<?php
    echo "123";
?>
```
````

You might additionally link to a live demo using a third-party demo hosting service. (Google finds [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/), I can't speak to the quality of the service).

Comment: it doesn't run the PHP code, just showing. I want to running code like the js code in question!

Comment: @No.The.Hi — I refer you to the first and last paragraphs of this answer.

Comment: why SO does not add this feature?

Comment: Probably because the cost / value ratio is poor.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the difference between client- and server-side code and the security implications thereof, you will understand why this is not, and probably never will be, a feature on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Can I keep asking for this feature until I do understand the difference?

Answer (score -5):

There isn't any way to run PHP code. You have to insert an additional link in your question/answer to share your PHP code snippet with fellow members.

A PHP code snippet can be shared by using the following websites:

http://www.writephponline.com/

http://phptester.net/  -  [My choice]

https://www.mycompiler.io/online-php-compiler

https://paiza.io/en/languages/online-php-editor

And many more. You can also google for this using "PHP code snippets online" keywords ;)

Comment: thank you @Peter Mortensen for wonderful editing